# Eliminar un carácter de una cadena PHP obtenido por simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, html, variables

de vuelta acudiendo a uds pues no he podido resolver este inconveniente.

Tengo el siguiente script en PHP. es simple, va a una URL, extrae el texto de una etiqueta especifica y lo imprime (Ver código)

```
    <?php
    require('simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $url = "http://www.eurosupermercados.com/producto/chorizo-con-ternera-zenu-500gr/"; 
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load_file($url); 
        $post = $html->find('p[class=price]', 0)->plaintext;
        $resultado = str_replace ( "$", '', $post);
        $resultado = str_replace ( ".", '', $resultado);
        echo $resultado;
    ?>
```

Esto lo que me imprime con base al link: (Ver imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan en el codigo, en estas 2 lineas elimino el punto y el signo de $

```
        $resultado = str_replace ( "$", '', $post);
        $resultado = str_replace ( ".", '', $resultado);
```

El punto lo elimina sin problemas, pero el signo no, por mas que intento no lo hace, entonces mire el codigo HTML de la pagina y resulta que las etiquetas estan asi: (Ver imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, hay 3 etiquetas, en la etiqueta **p** es la que contiene el precio que esta en una etiqueta **span** pero dentro de esta hay otro **span** que contiene unicamente el signo. Entonces creo que es por esto que no me lo elimina, es como si no hiciera parte del string.

En el codigo probe cambiar la etiqueta **p=[class=price]** por **span[class=woocommerce-Price-amount amount]** pero el resultado es **$0**, es decir, me toma el signo pero no el precio.

**Alguno puede indicarme como puedo eliminar este signo para tener solo el numero?**

Muchas Gracias a todos de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema que presentas, es que $ es un caracter especial por php, y tú estás con un complemento HTML, por lo que el replace debería ser:

```
$resultado = str_replace ( '&#36;', '', $post);
```

A mi me ha funcionado adjunto foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que finalmente, el código sería:

```
 <?php
require('simple_html_dom.php'); 
$url = "http://www.eurosupermercados.com/producto/chorizo-con-ternera-zenu-500gr/"; 
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url); 
    $post = $html->find('p[class=price]', 0)->plaintext;
    $resultado = str_replace ( '&#36;', '', $post);
    $resultado = str_replace ( ".", '', $resultado);

    echo $resultado;
?>
```

Comment: Excelente. Fue tal cual. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @JuanFernandez gracias, aunque quizás llegué un poco tarde :)

Answer (score 0):

Probaste poniendo el monto dentro de un `<p>` o un `<label>` y ponerle una clase a estos?
Tambien se me ocurre usar la funcion split(' ') despues de la replace para separar lo que te queda usando el espacio, luego tomar el segundo elemento del array resultante.

Comment: Revisar [answer]. Las respuestas no deben pedir aclaración de la pregunta.

Comment: Lo he solucionado con substr me sirvio. Muchas gracias.